# Need help setting up sweep function for signal generator

Tags: function-generator

I recently bought a signal generator from Amazon.  The model I got was the UDB1205s but I believe my question applies to any of the manufacturer's signal generator in the UDB120x series.  A similar unit appears to be sold as the DDS SG100x series.

Frankly, I have no idea who the manufacturer is.  It was shipped directly from China, and has no markers except for the model number on the bottom.  It is sold by several distributors.

[image]

It generates sine, triangle and square waves from 0.1 Hz up to 5 MHz.  It also has a sweep function.  I like it a lot, and it performs just as advertised.

The problem is, there was no manual sent with the product, either printed or electronic, and I cannot find one online.  I have used an earlier version of this product (UDB 1000x series) that did not have the sweep function, and I was able to figure out all the functions by just playing around.  However I have not been able to figure out the sweep functionality on this unit.

Obviously one needs to be able to setup the starting and ending frequencies.  But regardless of what frequency I set the unit to, if I enable the sweep function the frequencies go from 1 KHz to 10 KHz and then repeat.

Does anyone here have experience with this unit, or know where an electronic copy of the manual can be found?

Answer (score 6):

Although I still wasn't able to find a manual online, in an ad for one of the products for the similar SG100x series (same as mine w/o an ADC or second TTL port), it mentions the sweep function going from frequency f1 to f2.  As mentioned in my question, I couldn't find any direct way to set the starting and ending frequencies, but seeing them labelled f1 and f2 got me thinking.

There is a Save function which saves the current parameter setup to one of 10 "slots", numbered 0 through 9.  Sure enough, setting up the starting frequency and saving the current setup as slot 1 (skipping slot 0), and then setting up the ending frequency and saving the setup as slot 2, and then setting the Sweep function to Run causes it to use these two frequencies as the start and end point.  All the the other parameters such as the signal type (square/triangle/square, sweep duration, etc. are taken from the current setup when Run is selected.

Rather obscure user interface.

**Update**

I was finally able to find the manual for my specific model online [here](http://www.cqbluejay.com/uploads/down/Agent_product/UDB12xxUsersManual.pdf).